# How to validate multiple sheets in Laravel excel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

I have figure it out how to validate one sheet in Laravel Excel. But I don't know how to differentiate validation by each sheet? Someone knows how to do it?

I have these validations for my **sheet-1**

```
return [
    "*.0" => ['required', 'integer'],
    "*.1" => ['required'],
    "*.2" => ['required', 'max:5'],
];
```

And validations for **sheet-2**

```
return [
    "*.0" => ['required'],
    "*.1" => ['required', 'exists:users'],
    "*.2" => ['required'],
    "*.3" => ['required', 'alpha'],
];
```

Comment: When dealing with multiple sheets in Laravel Excel, each sheet should have a separate import/export file. You then combine those sheets by using a parent import/export and the `WithMultipleSheets` concern.  So to import/export 2 sheets, you need a total of 3 files. You don't need to differentiate between the validations because they should each be in different files.

Comment: @matticustard thanks for the tip sir. Yeah I just realized that we can create a parent import for two imports and add with each validation. thanks again. i'll close this.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the validation by sheet index so that each sheet will have it's own validation. To do that you need to implement `WithMultipleSheets` contract. In your case that would be like this:

```
namespace App\Imports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class SheetImport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
    public function sheets(): array
    {
        return [
            0 => new class implements ToCollection, WithValidation
            {
                public function rules(): array
                {
                    return [
                        "*.0" => ['required', 'integer'],
                        "*.1" => ['required'],
                        "*.2" => ['required', 'max:5'],
                    ];
                }
            },
            1 => new class implements ToCollection, WithValidation
            {
                public function rules(): array
                {
                    return [
                        "*.0" => ['required'],
                        "*.1" => ['required', 'exists:users'],
                        "*.2" => ['required'],
                        "*.3" => ['required', 'alpha'],
                    ];
                }
            },
        ];
    }
}
```

Note that sheet indices start at zero. You can also create sheep import classes separately as explained at [Laravel Excel - Multiple Sheets](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/multiple-sheets.html#multiple-sheets). The point is that you return sheet import objects from `sheets` method.

Comment: thanks for the effort of making solution. but I just solved it by separating two imports.